# How to restore timezone from RHEL 5.x to RHEL 7.x?

Tags: shell, command-line, rhel, date, timezone

We have scripts to reinstall `RHEL 5.x` to `RHEL 7.x` and install our application, but I need to update timezone according to old one. So how to restore timezone from RHEL 5.x to RHEL 7.x using `/etc/localtime` file (We are taking backup) and in command line?

One of the specific environment is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.8 (Tikanga)` and `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)`

Comment: So pointing localtime to your time zone file in your script doesn’t work?

Comment: @FrontENG : as the servers might be in different timezones, that won't work I guess.

Comment: do you have ansible or some kind of remote management?

Comment: @FrontENG unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In `RHEL 5.x`, there is a file `/etc/sysconfig/clock` contains the timezone. Using `sed` in the script to get the `timezone` from that file worked out. Sample output of this file:

```
ZONE="America/Chicago"
UTC=false
ARC=false
```

Thanks!